# Return substring before dash followed by a digit in bash

Tags: string, bash, shell, pattern-matching, substring

I have a string that can be one of:

1.) `AA_BB-CC_xxxx-xx.y.y-xxxxxxxx-yyyyyy.tar.gz`

or with prefix dropped:

2.) `CC_xxxx-xx.y.y-xxxxxxxx-yyyyyy.tar.gz`

where A,B,C,D are any number of letters and x and y are digits.  I need to extract the following from the above:

```
AA_BB-CC_xxxx
CC_xxxx
```

Example:

```
standalone_version-WIN_2012-16.3.2-20180627-131137.tar.gz
WIN_2008-16.3.2-20180614-094525.tar.gz
```

need to extract:

```
standalone_version-WIN_2012
WIN-2008
```

I'm trying to discard everything from the end till the first dash followed by a digit is encountered.  I'm using the following but it returns the whole string:

```
name=${image_file%%-[0-9].*}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there!  Instead of

```
name=${image_file%%-[0-9].*}
```

omit the dot:

```
name=${image_file%%-[0-9]*}
```

The expressions in bash `%%` string trims are [patterns](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern), not regular expressions.  Therefore `*` alone matches any number of characters, not `.*` as in a regex.

Example (tested in bash 4.4.12(3)-release):

```
$ foo='standalone_version-WIN_2012-16.3.2-20180627-131137.tar.gz'
$ bar='WIN_2008-16.3.2-20180614-094525.tar.gz'
$ echo ${foo%%-[0-9].*}
standalone_version-WIN_2012-16.3.2-20180627-131137.tar.gz
    # oops
$ echo ${foo%%-[0-9]*}
standalone_version-WIN_2012
    # no dot - works fine
$ echo ${bar%%-[0-9]*}
WIN_2008
    # same here.
```